# Laravel Excel paper size setup

Tags: php, excel, laravel, pdf

I'm using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel package to generate some payment bills.
I generate the excel and then export it to pdf (vía ->download('pdf') method) so the user can download it and print it without any hassle.
This may not be the most elegant way, but I found this way pretty straightforward and easy to implement.
I need to generate the pdf in half letter paper size to match the paper sheets that have been pre-printed with logos and stuff in specific positions.

I can't find in the docs how to change paper size or pdf exporting options.
Thank you.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with this, what code are you using to generate the pdf? Seems you could specify the page size with something like `return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('DLPDF')`

Comment: Hi, I'm using the code from the website http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export, what I need is to specify Half Letter paper size (Like custom page size or something). Thanks for your response.

Comment: The [reference guide](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/reference-guide) says `$sheet->set{$property}()` can be used with property `paperSize`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to put this in your `$sheet` code:

```
$sheet->setpaperSize(1);// in my case 1 represents Letter.
```